How to update axis labels in Plotly Dashboard?
I am using the following code to monitor an output file from another application named TOUGH.
I define a graph component and update its figure using the update_graph_live() call back function. In order for my graphs to remain legible, I adjust the x-axis time units. But although the data appears to update correctly, the x-axis labels remain what they were when the app is initially launched, despite me returning the figure as part of the callback function. I run the script from Spyder IDE in an Anaconda virtual env.
I've scratched my head some more when I actually checked the Dash debugger and saw that my debugging counter was actually incrementing fine on the Dashboard, but somehow the figure is not updated.

Any help would be most welcome.
Here is what the dash looks like:

import os
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash import Dash, dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Create Dash app
app = Dash(__name__)

# Layout of the app
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(
        id='file-path',
        type='text',
        placeholder='Enter the file path...',
        style={'width': '100%'}
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=True),
    dcc.Interval(
        id='graph-update',
        interval=1000,  # in milliseconds (1 seconds)
        n_intervals=0
    )
])

def load_data(file_path):
    try:
        data = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=0, skiprows=0, index_col=False)
        new_headers = [s.strip() for s in data.columns.values] # remove whitespaces
        data.columns = new_headers

        # Adjust the times in a legible unit
        max_time = data["TIME(S)"].max()
        if max_time > 2 * 365 * 24 * 3600:
            data["TIME(Years)"] = data["TIME(S)"] / (365 * 24 * 3600)
            time_col = "TIME(Years)"
            time_label = "Time (Years)"
        elif max_time > 2 * 30 * 24 * 3600:
            data["TIME(Months)"] = data["TIME(S)"] / (30 * 24 * 3600)
            time_col = "TIME(Months)"
            time_label = "Time (Months)"
        elif max_time > 2 * 7 * 24 * 3600:
            data["TIME(Weeks)"] = data["TIME(S)"] / (7 * 24 * 3600)
            time_col = "TIME(Weeks)"
            time_label = "Time (Weeks)"
        elif max_time > 1 * 24 * 3600:
            data["TIME(Days)"] = data["TIME(S)"] / (24 * 3600)
            time_col = "TIME(Days)"
            time_label = "Time (Days)"
        elif max_time > 0.5 * 3600:
            data["TIME(Hours)"] = data["TIME(S)"] / 3600
            time_col = "TIME(Hours)"
            time_label = "Time (Hours)"
        elif max_time > 24:
            data["TIME(Minutes)"] = data["TIME(S)"] / 60
            time_col = "TIME(Minutes)"
            time_label = "Time (Minutes)"
        else:
            time_col = "TIME(S)"
            time_label = "Time (Seconds)"
        print(time_label)
        data.iloc[:, 1:] = data.iloc[:, 1:].apply(pd.to_numeric)
        return data, time_col, time_label
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error loading data: {e}")
        return None, None, None

@app.callback(
    Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')],
    [State('file-path', 'value')]
)
def update_graph_live(n_intervals, file_path):
    if not file_path or not os.path.exists(file_path):
        return go.Figure()

    data, time_col, time_label = load_data(file_path)
    if data is None:
        return go.Figure()

    time = data[time_col]
    pressure = data["PRES"]
    temperature = data["TEMP"]
    saturation_gas = data["SAT_Gas"]
    saturation_aqu = data["SAT_Aqu"]
    time_diff = data["TIME(S)"].diff().dropna()

    fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=3, subplot_titles=("Pressure vs Time", "Molar Fractions vs Time", "Time Difference vs Time", "Temperature vs Time", "Saturation vs Time"))

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=time, y=pressure, mode='lines', name='Pressure (Pa)', line=dict(color='blue')), row=1, col=1)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=time, y=temperature, mode='lines', name='Temperature (°C)', line=dict(color='red')), row=2, col=1)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=time, y=saturation_gas, mode='lines', name='Gas Phase Saturation', line=dict(color='green')), row=2, col=2)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=time, y=saturation_aqu, mode='lines', name='Aqueous Phase Saturation', line=dict(color='blue')), row=2, col=2)
    
    # just sorting out some colouring and styling for legibility
    for col in data.columns[6:]:
        color = 'black'
        linestyle = 'solid'
        if 'H2' in col:
            color = 'green'
        elif 'CH4' in col:
            color = 'lightblue'
        elif 'water' in col:
            color = 'blue'
        
        if 'Gas' in col:
            linestyle = 'solid'
        elif 'Aqu' in col:
            linestyle = 'dash'
            
        if 'TIME' in col:
            continue

        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=time, y=data[col], mode='lines', name=col, line=dict(color=color, dash=linestyle)), row=1, col=2)

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=time.iloc[1:len(time_diff)+1], y=time_diff, mode='lines', name='Time Step Size', line=dict(color='purple')), row=1, col=3)

    # # PREVIOUS ATTEMPT
    # fig.update_layout(
    #     title='Real-Time TOUGH Simulation Data', 
    #     showlegend=True,
    #     yaxis3_type='log'  # Setting the y-axis of the third subplot to log scale
    # )
    
    # PREVIOUS ATTEMPT
    # # Update x-axis labels individually
    # fig.update_xaxes(title_text=time_label, row=1, col=1)
    # fig.update_xaxes(title_text=time_label, row=1, col=2)
    # fig.update_xaxes(title_text=time_label, row=1, col=3)
    # fig.update_xaxes(title_text=time_label, row=2, col=1)
    # fig.update_xaxes(title_text=time_label, row=2, col=2)
    
    # CURRENT ATTEMPT
    fig.update_layout(
    title='Real-Time TOUGH Simulation Data', 
    showlegend=True,
    yaxis3_type='log',  # Setting the y-axis of the third subplot to log scale
    xaxis_title_text=time_label+str(n_intervals),  # Update x-axis 
    # labels. I add the interval counter for debugging
    xaxis2_title_text=time_label,
    xaxis3_title_text=time_label,
    xaxis4_title_text=time_label,
    xaxis5_title_text=time_label
)
    print('Update> ',time_label) # just a sanity check which demonstrates that the time
    #  conversion and label change is being read correctly - which it is
    
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text='Pressure (Pa)', row=1, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text='Molar Fraction (-)', row=1, col=2)
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text='Timestep (s)', row=1, col=3)
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text='Temperature (°C)', row=2, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text= 'Saturation (-)', row=2, col=2)


    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8050)


I had similar issue in the past, this is due to setting animate=True on the Graph component : when updating the figure, the data updates are properly applied but for some reason the layout updates are not. By the way, the animate option is still in beta :

animate (boolean; default False): Beta - If True, animate between
updates using plotly.js's animate function.

One way to solve this is to apply the missing layout updates "manually" using javascript/Plotly.js : we can use a MutationObserver to grab the plotly graph div as soon as it is loaded into the DOM (there is no Dash/Plotly event to do this easily), and once the element is ready we can register a plotly_animated handler on it to be able to respond to figure updates, that is, by applying the missing properties using Plotly.relayout function.
Create a .js file in your assets folder (@see Adding Static Assets), with the following code :
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // Root node to be observed for mutations
  const root = document.getElementById('_dash-app-content');

  // Observe root's children as they are added to the DOM
  new MutationObserver((mutationRecords, observer) => {
    for (const record of mutationRecords) {
      const nodes = record.addedNodes;
      if (!nodes.length) continue;

      if ([...nodes].some(node => node.className === 'plot-container plotly')) {
        // `gd` is the Plotly graph div (which is now fully loaded)
        const gd = record.target;

        // Register the plotly handler that will apply the missing layout updates
        // after each animation. Note the `gd.layout` object is updated properly
        // but the updates are not applied to the plot until we call `Plotly.relayout`
        gd.on('plotly_animated', () => {
          Plotly.relayout(gd, {
            'xaxis.title.text': gd.layout.xaxis.title.text,
            'xaxis2.title.text': gd.layout.xaxis2.title.text,
            'xaxis3.title.text': gd.layout.xaxis3.title.text,
            'xaxis4.title.text': gd.layout.xaxis4.title.text,
            'xaxis5.title.text': gd.layout.xaxis5.title.text
          });
        });

        observer.disconnect();
        break;
      }
    }
  }).observe(root, { childList: true, subtree: true });
});

